Unable to Redirect to Specific Page on Notification Tap in Flutter Firebase Messaging
I'm working on a Flutter app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications. I've implemented a notification handler to redirect the user to a specific page when they tap on a notification. However, the redirection is not working as expected.
Code Snippet
Here’s my Messaging class responsible for handling notifications:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import '../../main.dart';
import '../../view/redeem_code/redeem_code.dart';

class Messaging {
  static final Messaging _instance = Messaging._internal();
  static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  static AndroidNotificationChannel? channel;
  static late FirebaseMessaging messaging;

  Messaging._internal();

  factory Messaging() => _instance;

  static Future<void> initialize() async {
    messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await createNotificationChannel();
    await setupForegroundMessaging();
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  }

  static Future<void> createNotificationChannel() async {
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel!);
  }

  static Future<void> setupForegroundMessaging() async {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    const iOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    const initSettings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!.initialize(
      initSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!.show(
          message.hashCode,
          message.notification!.title,
          message.notification!.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel!.id,
              channel!.name,
              channelDescription: channel!.description,
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });

    await messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  static Future<String?> getFCM() async {
    final fcmToken = await messaging.getToken();
    return fcmToken;
  }
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  final message = notificationResponse.payload;
  if (message != null && message.isNotEmpty) {
    var data = jsonDecode(message);
    var redirect = data["redirect"];
    if (redirect == "redeemcode") {
      navigatorKey.currentState?.push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const RedeemCode(),
      ));
    }
  }
  print(
      'Notification action tapped: ${notificationResponse.actionId} with payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
}


Issue

Redirection Not Working: When I tap on the notification, it does not redirect me to the RedeemCode page. The navigatorKey is defined globally in my main.dart, but it seems the currentState is not available or not functioning as expected.

Payload Handling: The payload received does contain the expected redirect URL. However, the redirection logic does not seem to be triggering.


What I Have Tried

I ensured the navigatorKey is correctly defined and accessible.
Verified that the payload format from the notification matches what I'm trying to decode.
Added print statements to check if the notification tap handler is being called.

Any Help?
I would appreciate any guidance on how to debug this issue or any suggestions on what I might be missing in my implementation. Thank you!
I would appreciate any guidance on how to debug this issue or any suggestions on what I might be missing in my implementation. Thank you!
